# Allow Italics Mid-Word

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Please allow *itallic*ness for part of a word.  This will allow highlighting which part of a word is important, or which part constitutes a language symbol, button name, etc.

Comment: *Exam*ple.....?

Comment: *Test*ing. Did it work? `[status-whatyoutalkinboutjeff]`

Comment: He probably meant "completed" in the sense that there is indeed a way to have italics mid-word: the way [Shog9 said](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62723/allow-italics-mid-word/62724#62724)

Comment: @Michael @Job I'd say this should've been marked `status-bydesign` or maybe a new status such as `status-workedaround`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Up*d*a**t**e: [intra-word emphasis is now supported in both posts and comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240354/markdown-change-intra-word-emphasis-now-works).

---

For normal posts, just use H*T*ML: `H<i>T</i>ML`

For comments, it would be nice... But the parsing done on comments is already weak compared to normal posts.

Comment: Comments should allow more markup, but that's another problem that I would bet already has a feature-request.

Comment: Wait, you can use HTML tags in posts?!?  Well, now I feel like an idiot.

Comment: @James: You can use a limited subset that is similar to what you can do with Markup. There are a few things that don't have don't have Markup equivalences. The ones that come to mind are strikeouts, superscripts, and subscripts.

Comment: @dmckee:  Yes, now I feel extra dumb, because I've used `<s>` and `<sup>` in quite a few posts.  I'm just going to be quiet now and pretend this moment of stupidity never happened.

Comment: Aren't you emphasizing the wrong letter?