# "Emphasis" markdown bug with Japanese characters in Japanese Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, unicode

*I assume this has something to do with [the recent change to how Markdown works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240354/markdown-change-intra-word-emphasis-now-works)*.

I noticed that Japanese SO exists from [this chat-bot message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18030216#18030216), and with some Japanese language skill that I have, was interested what question was that about (because it seems it doesn't have anything to do with programming!).

Turn out [the site](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/login) is still (or will be?) in private beta, but wait, is that unescaped markdown for "emphasis"?

Quote:

> `警告:現在このサイトは少なくとも あと数日 日間**プライベート ベータ**です。`

(Removing the code block will fix the problem here on MSE)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This change was done to help support Asian language support (it has been a [long-standing issue on Japanese.SE](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120/issues-with-bolding), and [Chinese SE as well](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/)), and yes, one of the Asian language sites would be the Japanese SO you have stumbled across.

As explained [in the post about the markdown changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240354/markdown-change-intra-word-emphasis-now-works):

> note that the rendered versions of questions and answers are not re-rendered until a post is edited, so this will not affect anything retroactively.

The reason it's still not right is because I haven't edited it yet. It's on my list of to-dos though!

Comment: [meta-tag:status-bydesign] means "this is by design and is not going to be changed", guess it's better to put [meta-tag:status-planned] now then [meta-tag:status-completed] when you edit and fix it.

Comment: Also, the link to Area 51 is broken (leading to Page Not Found) since this site doesn't have any Area 51 proposal.

Comment: @Shadow, in this case it isn't a bug. It is behaving as a change said it would behave which is why I marked it bydesign. I think it'll be okay, I will get the no access allowed landing page fixed in the future, don't worry.

Comment: There's a known issue in MarkdownMini which we are working on.

Comment: The focus on Japanese SO right now is finishing and fixing the translations, and getting an initial community of enthused people in there (while still in private) to test _everything_ thoroughly while asking and answering some questions. We'll polish up everything else (including a stub Area 51 proposal just so everything works) when we're much closer to actually opening it up, which will be sometime near the end of this year. Our primary goal right now is to continue to fix a bunch of the translations.