# Minor problems with bold markdown for Japanese (on chat and in posts)

Tags: bug, chat, markdown, markdown-rendering

Although [bold markdown has finally been fixed for Japanese](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240354/markdown-change-intra-word-emphasis-now-works), there are still occasional problems.  I first noticed these problems in chat; it seems like there are related problems on the main site, but the behavior is slightly different in chat, so I'll try to illustrate both behaviors here.

I've created [a test chat room with two problematic messages](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18458/japanese-bold-test-room):

```
1. 行こうか**どうしようか**　＝　行こうか**？？か**
2. 「許さない、（許さないのは）**絶対に**だ！」　→　「 許さない、**絶対に**だ！」
```

In this chat room, the messages render like this:

[image: bold chat rendering]

To compare with the main site, I entered the same messages into [an answer on the formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243159/215040).  I found that the first message has the same problem, but the second message renders correctly:

[image: bold answer rendering]

It's really nice being able to use bold markdown with Japanese!  And it usually works fine now, so this should probably be considered a minor bug.  But it would be nicer still if it worked more reliably.