# Not all UTF-8 characters supported

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, unicode

I can't create a post with the [following characters](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=4b9m2Y4K).

There are errors for both the Japanese and Chinese characters.

Here is the post in question [What languages does the character encoding UTF-8 support?](https://superuser.com/questions/946612). It is peculiar that it supports 59 languages besides Japanese and Chinese.

Comment: It seems to be Unihan characters that aren't allowed.  If I remove the single Chinese character from your Japanese example, it doesn't trigger an error.  Made-in-Japan Unihan characters like U+8FBB do trigger the error.  The filter doesn't seem to be in place on language sites.

Comment: What site are you trying to post that on?  Here?

Comment: @tchrist superuser.com originally, but the same issue appears here to.

Comment: @LiamWilliam Does SU usually get postings with Unihan in it?  Seems like the wrong target audience to me. :)

Comment: @tchrist here is the post in question http://superuser.com/questions/946612 No it doesn't but it is peculiar that it supports 59 languages besides Japanese and Chinese.

Comment: @tchrist I've used Unihan here in what I think are legitimate posts: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243160/

Comment: I am unsure why spammers would bother sending Chinese spam to a website which is used almost exclusively by non-Chinese speakers.

Comment: @MarchHo Well I think Japanese probably do and a subset of Japanese includes Chinese.  But either way you are right it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I have a workaround:

> 什麽是Unicode(統一碼/標準萬國碼)? in Trad'l Chinese
>   什么是Unicode(统一码)? in Simplified
>   Chinese
>   ユニコードとは何か？in Japanese

If you replace the Unihan characters with HTML entities representing those characters, they go through the filter (as of this writing).  That is, replace `何` with `&#x4F55;`, and so on.

The post you linked to in your comment uses Markdown to create a block of preformatted text.  But HTML entities won't show up properly in that sort of text block.  If you try putting in HTML entities right now, it'll end up like this:

```
&#x4EC0;&#x9EBD;&#x662F;Unicode(&#x7D71;&#x4E00;&#x78BC;/&#x6A19;&#x6E96;&#x842C;&#x570B;&#x78BC;)? in Trad'l Chinese  
&#x4EC0;&#x4E48;&#x662F;Unicode(&#x7EDF;&#x4E00;&#x7801;)? in Simplified Chinese  
&#x30E6;&#x30CB;&#x30B3;&#x30FC;&#x30C9;&#x3068;&#x306F;&#x4F55;&#x304B;&#xFF1F;in Japanese
```

To get the entities to show up properly, you'll have to use the HTML `<pre>` tag instead, like this:

```
什麽是Unicode(統一碼/標準萬國碼)? in Trad'l Chinese  
什么是Unicode(统一码)? in Simplified Chinese  
ユニコードとは何か？in Japanese
```

That should solve your problem for the time being.

Comment: A webservice to convert these strings can be found [here](http://www.cozychinese.com/convert/)

Answer (score 12):

There’s been a lot of CJK spam on SU and Meta lately; probably that’s why it’s **Forbidden**.

---

Zap!

[image: the red zapper forbids U+4EC0]

If it had let me enter it, this posting would have looked something like this:

[image: image of forbidden character posting of U+4EC0]

That character is:

```
U+4EC0  CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-4EC0
  Mandarin     SHI2 SHEN2
  Cantonese    sam6 sap6 zaap6
  JapaneseKun  KUMI TOU MAJIRU
  JapaneseOn   SHUU JUU
  Korean       SIP CIP
  HanyuPinlu   shen2(4045) shen5(17)
  Vietnamese   thập
```

Comment: This is correct. We were getting a deluge of Chinese-language spam, and it was evolving so we just blocked Chinese characters. At some point in the future we will re-enable Chinese.

Comment: @jmac is this status-by-design then?

Comment: @MarcGravell currently yes, but will soon be [status-completed] at an indeterminate amount of time in the future.

Comment: @MarcGravell, could you please consider adding linguistics.se to the sites where Chinese characters are allowed? Probably does not attract that much spam...

Comment: @jmac Travel.SE as well, please.

Comment: @jpatokal - sorted for you.

Comment: @Oded We regularly have questions and answers on [english.se] that need Unihan characters as well—can we have it back there as well, please?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ELU was one of the targets. Perhaps Unihan should be a rep-based privilege.

Comment: @tchrist That would work, I guess. 125 rep to use Arabic and Unihan (assuming the ban on Arabic is still in place at all; I haven't tested).

Comment: @jmac presumably the spam posts are 100% Chinese, whereas legit posts would be 80%+ English with quoted Chinese characters. Couldn't you put in less obtrusive rules like, posts must be 50%+ non-Chinese characters, instead of banning Chinese characters completely?

Comment: @user568458 are you a spammer?  Just kidding.  :)  I think this would almost be more confusing to users.  1 shorter and it's an invalid post doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Oded: it seems you reenabled Chinese language on Travel, and now Travel is hit with lots of Chinese-language spam questions again.  The pattern I've seen the last couple days is questions posted with tons of Chinese text and a bit of English which is the name of a well-known university (not the same one each time).  I think we should revisit the enablement of Chinese on Travel, at least in titles or when it occupies over 50% of the question text.  I translated (using Google) one of the spam posts, and it seems to be a service advertising fake US diplomas and gives a Tencent/QQ contact number.

Comment: @JohnZwinck - we don't have the tooling (at the moment) to do such blocking (based on % of Chinese characters in the post). There is work on progress to fix that. Currently - it is all or nothing.

Comment: @Oded: we are still getting hammered with Chinese diploma mill spam in Travel.SE.  Something needs to be done promptly, as many times I come to look at the latest questions and the same spam is on top.  Here's the latest one for reference: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56667/

Comment: @JohnZwinck - I see one commonality - the use of a `@.qq.com` domain/email. I can blacklist that and see if that helps.

Comment: @Oded: thank you.  They use qq.com as their messaging platform (that's what the message tells you to contact, if you can read it).

Comment: @Oded It'd be really nice if you put in some exception logic (minimum account age and reputation?) to make this less painful for users.  I posted a workaround for posts, but I don't know of any way to work around the problem in comments.  Right now it can be frustrating being unable to reply to users with banned characters in their names.

Comment: @snailboat - Tim Post is looking into that.

Comment: @snailboat `@`-replying to users with banned characters in their name is fixed now: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267179/259381

Comment: CJK = [Chinese Japanese Korean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Symbols_and_Punctuation)