# "Comments cannot contain" user's name

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, unicode

I just tried to reply to a comment from a user with the handle:

```
Ciro Santilli 六四事件 法轮功 纳米比亚 威视
```

When I typed `@Ci` the system autocompleted it for me, but when I finished the comment and pressed enter I got a big red box saying *"Comments cannot contain that content"*.  There was nothing unusual about the comment; I've written literally thousands upon thousands of them and never seen this. Removing the user name solved the issue.

This means it is impossible to respond via ping to that user.

Comment: On which site? There's a temporary blacklist of some Chinese characters on some sites due to a wave of Chinese spam. It's probably time to take it out.

Comment: @Gilles Unix & Linux

Comment: Have a look at this: [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) Specifically related is the "How do the names get matched?" section (Can't link directly, sorry)

Comment: The workaround given by rene isn't available for names that are entirely in Chinese... There isn't really a reason to blacklist Chinese in comments, which require 50 rep and may well contain someone's name written in their native language's characters.

Comment: @Norm I guess they put a low level patch for all "layers" - it was quick and dirty hack to stop a spam flood

Comment: @MarcGravell Why is this by design? Shouldn't the blacklist be removed?

Comment: Related: [Comment can't contain user name containing non-Latin characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276724/289905).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is caused by the [spam prevention rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261611/158100) that got implemented on some sites due to the amount of spam with CJK characters.

You could work around the limitation to only use `@CiroSantilli` and remove the non-latin characters.

Comment: Yep, that worked.

Comment: Yup, and even `@Cir` is enough, /cc @gol