# Comment can't contain user name containing non-Latin characters

Tags: bug, comments, unicode

In a comment I was using `@` to address the username `طالب-التوحيد` and I got the error message "Comments cannot contain the content". As the comment also contained code, this wasn't the most descriptive message.

[image: screen shot of trying to add comment]

[Here is the original question.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/116995/cant-get-into-damn-vulnerable-web-app-with-hydra-even-though-correct-password-i)

Comment: Dunno, it could be to prevent spam.

Comment: Seen a rash of primarily-in-Arabic spam lately, so the blacklist is probably still in effect. Not so much for non-Latin characters, but targeting that particular range of unicode. I'll see if it's still needed tomorrow morning.

Comment: @IͶΔ Test. Seems to work fine for your name :>

Comment: @Seth I'm too cool not to be pingable on desktop. ᕙ(⇀‸↼‶)ᕗ

Comment: @IͶΔ That somehow affects my philosophy of life more than I feel like it should... ／人◕ __ ◕人＼

Comment: Related: [“Comments cannot contain” user's name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263416/289905).