# I can't write Chinese characters in edited posts, but OP could when posting

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, spam, quality-filter

*Note [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285287/overzealous-spam-filter-triggers-on-chinese-characters-in-the-help-and-improvem?noredirect=1&lq=1) is related, but not exactly the same, as this posts asks why OP **could** post (but I couldn't), whereas the other one states that OP **shouldn't be able to.***

Following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41571210/how-to-filter-block-bot-request-for-a-webservice-in-iis):

[image: Question body]

All I tried to do was a retag (remove inappropiate [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) tag) and remove unnecessary content (thanks).

Though, I couldn't submit my edit. This was the error I was getting:

[image: Error body]

Just to clarify, this is the **original** question body, **fully** unmodified (apart from the "TIA" I removed):

[image: Markdown]

My question now, **why can't I post his post containing Chinese characters?** And more importantly,

### Why could OP post this, but I cannot?

*Yes, I understand you shouldn't attempt to salvage very low quality questions. I just wanted to retag it, because it doesn't belong in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).*

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow has its own Meta site.

Comment: @Catija Can be reproduced on any stackexchange site.

Comment: @devRicher: Well, almost any; I don't believe it would trigger on chinese.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression that blocks these is pretty simple; if you poke around a bit, you'll probably find some workarounds. The author used such a workaround, which was then stripped automatically as the post was created, leaving you to encounter the block.

I've adjusted the expression, both to make it less sensitive and a little bit less easy to work around.