# How can I solve the 'Body cannot contain ""' error when trying to post?

Tags: support, unicode, blocklist

I get a `Body cannot contain ""` error when trying to post this question on SE. How can I resolve it?

> What is the best way to unpack `SequenceMatcher` loop results in
> Python so that values can be easily accessed and processed?
>
> ```
> from difflib import *
>
> orig =
> "陳仲舉言為士則，行為世範，登車攬轡，有澄清天下之志。為豫章太守，至，便問徐孺子所在，欲先看之。主簿白：「群情欲府君先入廨。」陳曰：「武王式商容之閭，席不暇煖。吾之禮賢，有何不可！」"
>
> commented =
> "陳仲舉言為士則，行為世範，登車攬轡，有澄清天下之志。汝南先賢傳曰：「陳蕃字仲舉，汝南平輿人。有室，荒蕪不埽除，曰：『大丈夫當為國家埽天下。』值漢桓之末，閹豎用事，外戚豪橫。及拜太傅，與大將軍竇武謀誅宦官，反為所害。」為豫章太守，海內先賢傳曰：「蕃為尚書，以忠正忤貴戚，不得在臺，遷豫章太守。」至，便問徐孺子所在，欲先看之。謝承後漢書曰：「徐稚字孺子，豫章南昌人。清妙高跱，超世絕俗。前後為諸公所闢，雖不就，及其死，萬里赴吊。常豫炙雞一隻，以綿漬酒中，暴乾以裹雞，徑到所赴塚隧外，以水漬綿，斗米飯，白茅為藉，以雞置前。酹酒畢，留謁即去，不見喪主。」主簿白：「群情欲府君先入廨。」陳曰：「武王式商容之閭，席不暇煗。許叔重曰：「商容，殷之賢人，老子師也。」車上跽曰式。吾之禮賢，有何不可！」袁宏漢紀曰：「蕃在豫章，為稚獨設一榻，去則懸之，見禮如此。」"
>
> diff = SequenceMatcher(None, orig, commented)
> ```
>
> The current iteration code stores match results in a list like this:
>
> ```
> match_id [Match(a=0, b=0, size=26), Match(a=26, b=108, size=6),
> Match(a=32, b=146, size=15), Match(a=47, b=273, size=30), Match(a=78,
> b=330, size=12), Match(a=90, b=372, size=0)]
> ```
>
> I'd eventually like to mark out the comments like so:
>
> ```
> 陳仲舉言為士則，行為世範，登車攬轡，有澄清天下之志。{{汝南先賢傳曰：「陳蕃字仲舉，汝南平輿人。有室，荒蕪不埽除，曰：『大丈夫當為國家埽天下。』值漢桓之末，閹豎用事，外戚豪橫。及拜太傅，與大將軍竇武謀誅宦官，反為所害。」}}為豫章太守，{{海內先賢傳曰：「蕃為尚書，以忠正忤貴戚，不得在臺，遷豫章太守。」}}至，便問徐孺子所在，欲先看之。{{謝承後漢書曰：「徐稚字孺子，豫章南昌人。清妙高跱，超世絕俗。前後為諸公所闢，雖不就，及其死，萬里赴吊。常豫炙雞一隻，以綿漬酒中，暴乾以裹雞，徑到所赴塚隧外，以水漬綿，斗米飯，白茅為藉，以雞置前。酹酒畢，留謁即去，不見喪主。」}}主簿白：「群情欲府君先入廨。」陳曰：「武王式商容之閭，席不暇煗。{{許叔重曰：「商容，殷之賢人，老子師也。」車上跽曰式。}}吾之禮賢，有何不可！」{{袁宏漢紀曰：「蕃在豫章，為稚獨設一榻，去則懸之，見禮如此。」}}
> ```
>
> Which means, I am interested in unpacking the above `SequenceMatcher`
> results and do some calculations on specific `b` and size` values to
> yield this sequence:
>
> ```
> rslt = [[0+26,108][108+6,146][146+15,273][273+30,330][330+12,372]]
> ```

Comment: Chinese characters are [blocked on most sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263724/323179) due to spam.

Comment: This is a great inconvenience for users working with CJK data. Is anyone working on fine-tuning the spam filter to allow legitimate posts containing Chinese characters?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Chinese characters are [blocked in posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263725/377214) network-wide, with the exception of a few sites (including this one), because of persistent spam posts that use them.

The error message is [intentionally kept nondescript](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311004/unable-to-edit-question-containing-non-latin-characters-warning-about-body-can) to prevent spammers from catching on to the real cause why their posts are being blocked.

tl;dr: spammers prevent us from having nice things...

Comment: Any workaround for this? I need to use the actual data as a sample.

Comment: @Sati Supposedly [there's a workaround](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285291/377214): making the first line of the post shorter than 10 characters may allow you to evade it, though it may have been plugged since. If that doesn't work, [replacing the characters with HTML entities might also work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261622/377214).

Comment: I use a simplified string of [integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59419950/6210219) to represent the original Chinese characters.

Comment: @Sati `orig = base64.b64decode("6Zmz5Luy6IiJ6KiA54K65aOr5YmH").decode("utf8");`

Answer (score 8):

As a workaround you can still provide the original message, but in base64 encoding and instruct readers on how to decode it, like using Notepad++ plugin MIME tools. This will prevent the original text from being immediately visible though, so any search engine queries would fail to find it probably.