# Question flagged as spam and error on body

Tags: support, spam

I am trying to post a question on Stack Overflow regarding a problem I found on my code, but when I try to post it, the site returns two errors, both not really clarifying what is wrong with the question, namely:

- Body cannot contain "". I am not sure of what the question cannot contain.
- This appears to be spam. If you think we've made an error, make a post in meta. I am not sure what triggers such error.

In any case, here is the question I would like to post:

> Greetings.
>
> I am working on a Python project that reads an CSV file to extract
> reviews, then it group the reviews by the host id in order to
> summarize them. I managed to open the file to read and group it by the
> host ids.
>
> However, I found a problem I could not solve: the reviews are written
> in many different languages such as: English, French, Spanish, Korean,
> Chinese, and others that I do not recognise. In an attempt to tackle
> it was translating all reviews to English, so I used a library named
> "translators" to translate the many languages.
>
> Also, my best bet at reading the file was using an encoding that would
> accept as many languages as possible, and the best result I got was
> using the Latin1 encoding, but it cannot read Chinese or Korean, which
> return a lot of strange symbols. For example:
>
> > 這次雖然只住了一晚,但房間很乾淨安靜,一家人也很和善,有種回到家的熟悉感。 希望下次有機會再到巴塞隆那能多住幾天。
>
> returns a bunch of hexadecimal values plus some gibberish, which
> throws an error when I try to translate into English because it does
> not recognize it as string.
>
> Botton line: I have two problems:
>
> - Some way to read all languages, so I could translate it to English.
> - Increase the code performance, for that it would be preferable that it does not attempt to translate English reviews, as it waste both
>   time and processing power. Since this is a pilot project, the latter
>   is more an extra point than really a need, but the former has been
>   giving me headaches for some time now.
>
> What I have up to now:
>
> ```
> import pandas as pd   
> from collections  import defaultdict, namedtuple  
> import csv    
> import translators as ts  
> import translators.server as tss
>     group_sentences = {}  
>     with open(file_name, 'r',encoding='latin1') as myfile: 
>         reader = csv.reader(myfile, delimiter=';')
>         for n, row in enumerate(reader):
>             if not n:
>                 continue  
>             listing_id, id, date, reviewer_id, reviewer_name, comments = row
>             if listing_id not in group_sentences:
>                 group_sentences[listing_id] = list()
>             if len(comments) > 10:
>                 group_sentences[listing_id].append(tss.google(comments))
> ```

How do I proceed? Is it a bug or I am missing something?

Comment: It's because of the Chinese characters in your post: [How can I solve the 'Body cannot contain ""' error when trying to post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340715/how-can-i-solve-the-body-cannot-contain-error-when-trying-to-post). This filter exists thanks to persistent spammers. The error is intentionally nondescript to prevent spammers from catching on.

Comment: As far as a workaround, [replacing the characters with HTML entities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261622/377214) is one way.

Comment: Related: *[Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)* and [Stack Overflow is not a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828)