# Stop telling Tor users to contact support for registration, if their request will be dismissed anyway

Tags: feature-request, error-message, sign-up, tor

When [Tor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(network))-users try to sign up, they consistently get this error message:

> <s>Something went wrong. Please contact us at community-support@stackoverflow.email for assistance.</s>

update: somewhere between 30 june and 18 july, the error message has been updated, it now reads:

> You cannot register at this time. If you continue to find this error, [contact us.](https://law.stackexchange.com/contact)

However this error-message is unhelpful, because when Tor users actually contact `community-support@stackoverflow.email` for assistance, they basically say:

> We cannot help you. We cannot create the account for you manually, and we cannot remove the tor signup block.
>
> Stop using Tor.

A more helpful error message is warranted IMO, maybe something like:

> (Unfortunately?) Tor users are not allowed to sign up at this time.

Comment: @JourneymanGeekOnStrike even so, SE should say it's officially blocked. (yeah I know how absurd it is to expect SE to be transparent about their actions these days. Just silly wishful thinking.)

Comment: The ambiguity reminds me of [the "*Body cannot contain ""*" error due to CJK characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340715/241919),

Comment: Possibly related? [Update on the ongoing DDoS attacks and blocking Tor exit nodes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376060/update-on-the-ongoing-ddos-attacks-and-blocking-tor-exit-nodes)

Comment: @Larnu maybe, but tor exit nodes are not blocked from browsing, they are not even blocked from logging in, the only thing they are blocked from, is signing up.

Comment: @Cerbrus Tor users are being instructed to contact specific people for help, some people who cannot help in any way, thus wasting everyone's time, wasting the Tor user's time for writing an email, and wasting the people monitoring `community-support@stackoverflow.email` 's time for having to read and respond to inquiries they cannot help with, and giving the tor user a false sense of hope (`surely the people over at community-support@stackoverflow.email can help me get registered`- false) - but the error message might be accidental rather than deliberate, i wouldn't know (it's closed-source)

Comment: @sonic I'm aware. Paraphrasing is often unhelpful as it hides exactly this sort of problem. Putting it in quote markdown further leads users to think that this is an actual quote, even if it says otherwise.

Comment: @Catija ticket number: 107527 - and the actual quote is ```Unfortunately, at this time, I am not able to lift this restriction nor we can't register users manually. You can try registering at another time from a different device and using different credentials or trying not using the proxy.```

Comment: @Cerbrus oh thanks. well yes, that *was* a direct copypaste of the error message, 1 july, but i just tried again, and now the error message has changed. the new error message text is ```You cannot register at this time.
If you continue to find this error, contact us.``` - with "contact us" being a clickable link to https://law.stackexchange.com/contact

Comment: As far as I'm aware, we haven't changed the error message - it's possible there are multiple messages depending on the problem you encounter. We have several systems in place that may intervene to prevent new account creations. As a note, @Cerbrus I was actually looking for the ticket response. :)

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps it would be useful to extend the error message slightly?

> You cannot register at this time.
> If you are using a service which obscures your real IP address,
> try turning it off.
> If you still continue to receive this error,
> [contact us](https://law.stackexchange.com/contact).

(I also changed *find* to *receive,* which I believe is more idiomatic here.)

Comment: "which obscures your real IP address (like Tor), ..."

Comment: @JanDoggen I guess, though there are many others, and you would expect the users to be able to identify whether they are using one, perhaps after some thinking.

Answer (score -8):

The solution to this is not to fix the error message.

The solution to this issue is to stop discrimination against [at-risk users](https://community.torproject.org/user-research/personas/) who need to use Tor to protect themselves.

Comment: Tor's great, but a lot of abuse comes from Tor. If you have a solution to that, feel free to write up a proposal and [ask](/questions/ask) it separately.

Comment: We already have moderation tools in-place. Use them. Wholesale blocking of Tor users is like saying "the internet is a source of abuse, so we shut off the internet from our server". It is not ethical to block Tor. It harms marginalized folks that need to use it to protect themselves.

Comment: Moderation tools and people are already at the break point without a free door from one of the worst sources of attack and abuse. Suggesting that it's unethical to protect the users here because some others need to protect themselves is unreasonable.

Comment: _"at-risk users who need to use Tor to protect themselves."_ Sorry, but nobody ___needs___ to use SE that badly. This is just entitlement.

Comment: "at-risk users / marginalized folks who need to use Tor to protect themselves" - I don't understand the category you describe. What could cause a person to have any more "need" than anyone else for such "protection"? What might such users be "at risk" *of*, and how could Tor "protect" them from such a "risk", even in principle? And why do you say "at-risk users" one time and "marginalized folks" the other time? Those seem to mean two completely unrelated things.

Comment: Finally: by "marginalized" I assume you are referring to a concept along the lines of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_group . Am I correct? If so: how could anyone else *know* that some person on the Internet is a member of such a group, *other than* such person *explicitly disclosing* the fact? If this is not possible, would it not then suffice for people to just... not explicitly disclose personally identifying information?

Comment: Examples of groups that need to use Tor and other technologies to protect themselves when searching for information online include: cancer patients, domestic abuse survivors, refugees, journalists, human rights workers, whistleblowers, etc

Comment: @KarlKnechtel There are plenty of people who can't use the clearnet safely. The legal definition of “protected group” is heuristic, _based on_ the real-world category of marginalised people, because such people need additional protections to ensure their safety; it's not the other way around. (If the designation of protected groups were arbitrary, I'd be the first to ignore it.)

Comment: Again: **what risk to "safety" are we contemplating here**? "because such people need additional protections to ensure their safety" - I don't believe this is the case; in fact, I don't see how it's possible in principle for this to be the case.

Comment: I also can't fathom the implied definition of "discrimination" in this post, or the reasoning behind it.

Comment: It might be helpful to outline how such usage actually looks. I fully understand that there are situations in which it is a risk to browse the internet in the clear, and I fully understand that there are situations in which one wants to browse SE - but where is the overlap? What is the risk of *browsing SE* in the clear?  Mind, this might just be naïveté from using the more technical sites and not being in a situation of risk, so this answer spelling out what the majority seems to miss would help.

Comment: It's different for each group. The cancer patients have a need to browse and ask questions related to healthcare information anonymously. The domestic abuse survivor or refugee's adversary would include their abuser that is threatening to kill them. Similarly many investigative journalists & human rights workers risk death. Whistleblowers may have very powerful adversaries and could be risking torture or death. But it's not just about browsing. These folks should be able to use SE to ask questions and publish content without endangering their lives or the lives of their loved ones.

Comment: @MichaelAltfield Again I get that certain people are at risk when performing certain actions in the clear, but this again skips how "use SE to ask questions and publish content" is such an action that poses a risk to the people. For example, I see how "investigative journalists & human rights workers risk death" but not how "investigative journalists & human rights workers risk death [by using SE]". SE doesn’t seem to cover the kind of content that is risky.

Comment: Because those user's adversaries can use their internet activity to physically locate them and harm them. When I give opsec trainings to at-risk users in the groups I've mentioned, I instruct them to use tools like Tor to protect themselves from their adversaries when using the Internet. Using Tor is not sufficient, but it is one necessary tool that they should be using to protect themselves.

Comment: @MichaelAltfield Please humor me; what internet activity is available to any non-moderator, non-staff member user of another user's activities on SE that could be used to locate them in the real world?  Since SE is the ground under discussion here, I feel it's a fair question.

Comment: @Daedalus a GET request.

Comment: @MichaelAltfield For us to believe you, you have to give us more than that.  The onus is on you to convince us/staff your point is valid if you want it implemented.

Comment: @Daedalus The reason  technologies like Tor exists is because it protects at-risk users from these attacks. You don't have to "believe me". If you want to educate yourself, then feel free to read-up on operations security, vulnerabilities in network security, and why at-risk users use Tor to protect themselves https://community.torproject.org/user-research/personas/

Comment: @MichaelAltfield You created the answer here; you can't expect us to do your research for you.  As I already said, the onus is on you to explain yourself.  If you can't do that, then why bother with this answer at all?  None of that answers my question directly, which is what information is available to the normal user that violates that security you speak of.  I did read up briefly on what information can be exposed in a GET request... from the server side.  None of that is available to the everyday user.

Comment: "a GET request" *conceivably* explains how an attacker could track down the source of a connection to Stack Exchange, *assuming* that said attacker is capable of compromising HTTPS somehow (by MITMing the ISP? Hacking SE to obtain server logs?). But it does not in any way explain how the attacker could possibly know *which connection* to track, i.e. how the attacker could *determine* that a particular account belongs to the target. For that matter, I can't even verify that "Michael Altfield" is your real name, from here, and I can't fathom how a sophisticated black-hat could do it, either.

Comment: At the risk of feeding the trolls. Yes: it's trivial for many adversaries to find someone's location with a simple GET request (assuming they've collected other internet activity, which is a trivial attack to most users not using Tor Browser). @KarlKnechtel I recommend reading about the programs that were leaked by Ed Snowden 10 years ago. And, more recently, the cyber-mercenary industry (eg NSO Group) and the great work done by Amnesty International and The Citizen Lab's investigations into these technologies being used against the aforementioned at-risk groups.

Comment: @MichaelAltfield So we're just trolls to you because we're asking for an in-depth explanation to your answer that lacks details?

Comment: @MichaelAltfield The technical background isn’t my doubt. Why would someone for whom a single GET can be problematic *want/need to use SO*?

Comment: Is there any explicit policy from SO not to allow registration? If not they either need to introduce it or fix the login process.