# Cannot register to music.stackexchange.com

Tags: support

I couldn't register to music.stackexchange.com—I kept getting this:

[image]

From the upper-right corner, we can see that I’ve already logged in, and when clicking on "Join this community" button, it just kept giving me the above errors.

I've been to the https://music.stackexchange.com/contact page, and have actually clicked on all possible options, and none appear to be the correct one:

[image]

Comment: Are you [using Tor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391323/323179)?

Comment: No, I'm accessing ***all*** of my SO sites just fine. This is the first one that I've having problem, @Laurel.

Comment: Your screenshot shows "If you continue to find this error, [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact)." Did you use that link to report the problem to SE staff, who are the only ones that might be able to actually help you? In other words, we can take a bug report here on MSE, but we just don't have the ability to help you resolve the types of issues which might be affecting your specific account, which the inclusion of the [tag:support] tag on this question makes it appear to be what you desire.

Comment: Easy, easy @Makyen, instead of accusing me doing anything wrong, a better attitude is point me to what exactly I should do. I've been to the https://music.stackexchange.com/contact, and have actually clicked on all possible options, and none appear to be the correct one. Example screenshot given in OP. IMHO, _"Which part of "If you continue to find this error, contact us" was unclear?"_ this kind of tone is really not necessary.

Comment: @xpt The "Other" -> "Other" option appears to be the appropriate option to use on the "Contact Us" page.

Comment: @xpt Yes, I agree that the initial wording of my first comment here was inappropriate. That's why I edited the comment shortly after posting it. I'm sorry both that I posted the initial version and that it caused you consternation.

Comment: My best guess is that you once had an account on that site, that got merged. Merge is the antichrist of Stack Exchange, always was, and causing them tons of bugs.