# Chinese text isn't working on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, unicode

When trying to post a Chinese string as part of the code in the question, [Given an offset dictionary and a string, create the BIO tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72849723/given-an-offset-dictionary-and-a-string-create-the-bio-tags)

SO is throwing the error:

> Body cannot contain "".
>
> This appears to be spam. If you think we've made an error, make a post in meta.

The code string that I wanted to post is on https://gist.githubusercontent.com/alvations/4c3460cf2dda5e19d828a8bace532216/raw/28190258c2be8ed7123033e77edefbf9201e1845/text

Comment: This is intentional; the technical sites tend to get lots of spam using Chinese characters: [Not all UTF-8 characters supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261609/not-all-utf-8-characters-supported). That post details a workaround.

Comment: I think your best chance might be posting it as a hexadecimal enconded string and include the conversion function in with the question.

Comment: Hmm... the answers at the "duplicate" links seem obsolete; see [my comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263724/unable-to-post-chinese-characters-due-to-validation-filter#comment1268210_263725) for examples where I've used Chinese characters on various sites.  And in 2015, [jmac wrote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261609/not-all-utf-8-characters-supported#comment853000_261611): "At some point in the future we will re-enable Chinese."  I'd be interested in a status update (I didn't know this ban existed).

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones based on [this MSO post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402161/2821954), at least it was still in effect in 2020.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones [the reopen item for this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/83380) was completed with "leave closed" before you contributed your comment. But I think your comment compiles enough info that this post warrants a reopen because rules on SO might be different (they get the bulk of the spam) from other network sites. Perhaps consider raising a costum mod flag asking to reopen the post and follow it up by placing a bounty?

Comment: In defense of the people who are voting to close (+remain close), it seems like the OP only wants to know why their particular question was unable to be posted.  In that case, fair enough: the question has been answered (it's an anti-spam measure).  So maybe it's better to ask another question asking about the current status: (a) which sites it applies to [currently], (b) where its disallowed (titles, question body, answers, tags, etc.), and (c) precisely which characters (Chinese, Japanese, Korean, etc.).

Comment: Okay, I whipped up a question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380154/351283).

Comment: Maybe a helpful message to ask users to post questions with chinese text in unicode would be more helpful than `Body cannot contain "".`