# "This appears to be spam. If you think we've made an error, make a post in meta." The link to "meta" isn't clickable

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, spam

In doing some testing for [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380154/351283), I repeated the steps in [How can I solve the 'Body cannot contain ""' error when trying to post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340715/351283) which gave the error:

> [image: Body cannot contain "". This appears to be spam. If you think we've made an error, make a post on meta. (The word "meta" is underline as if it's a link.)]

However, if I left-click the "meta" link, it doesn't do anything.  If I right-click and select "copy link", it copies:

```
http://meta.stackexchange.com"
```

"View Page Source" doesn't show the relevant text.  I'm on Firefox for Linux Mint 101.0.1 (64 bit).

It looks like a bug (maybe a typo).  Although, given how the question is likely going to be closed as a duplicate (like [these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/263724)), it might be an anti-bot feature.

Comment: "View Page Source" typically only shows the HTML which was initially delivered, which doesn't contain anything added by JavaScript. This, and almost all dynamic content, is added by JavaScript and won't be in "View Page Source". You would need to wait until it's displayed, or at least in the DOM, and then use the browser's DOM inspector (F12 then "Elements" tab in Chrome; F12 and "Inspector" tab in Firefox; both have a small button to the left of those tabs which allows you to select the element in the page with the mouse; both have "Inspect" in the right-click context menu within the page).