# Body cannot contain character?

Tags: bug

I was about to post an answer to a PPCG question when I got this error:

[image: picture of error]

It's an [LZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78)-compressed string that reads `Hello, World!`. I see no reason as to why this character is blocked, as it's just some random Unicode character. Hopefully it's not some emoticon of some illegal cupcake that doesn't show up on my Windows XP machine...

Comment: Well, no need to attempt to dump raw binary in a post so it is not a general problem. Anyway, the character code is not be the one for a blank square, but instead one that *is* invalid and only gets displayed as the default Missing Glyph character in this font.

Comment: @Jongware When it's code for an esolang, it is a problem.

Comment: Some characters are banned because they occurred 99.999% in spam only. Your markup is the other 0.001% so is tarred with the same brush.

Comment: Why not use hexadecimal, or string literal notation with escape codes? That way you can actually be sure readers of your post can reproduce the value. Posting raw binary data in a post is never helpful.

Comment: It's almost certainly this bug / feature: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261609/not-all-utf-8-characters-supported

Comment: And as @Martijn notes, the standard work-around is to post a hex / base64 dump of your code instead.

Comment: As you seem to want it on a a line by itself anyway (did you type two spaces after that first line?): what if you add a blank line and then format as code by indenting with 4 spaces, instead of manually doing `<pre>`?