# Is the baked HTML of past revisions saved anywhere?

Tags: support, revisions-list, markdown-rendering

Is the baked HTML of the old revisions of a post available anywhere?

I am aware that you can get the *markdown* of old revisions of a post by looking at the "source" links on /posts/###/revisions (and also in the PostHistory table in SEDE), but this is not strictly equivalent to viewing the baked HTML, since modifications have been made to the markdown-to-HTML renderer over time.

The immediate reason I am asking is this: following [balpha's fixes to how intra-word emphasis works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240354/224428), some posts on Japanese.SE needed to be re-baked to pick up the fixes. Here is the revisions list of one such post, which I made an edit to to trigger re-baking: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/posts/5001/revisions. However, it seems like both revisions of the post are being rendered fresh from the markdown source, which means that the old-renderer version of revision 1 is not shown, and so it looks like no re-baking actually occurred. So now my revision comment makes me look like a crazy man.

This is no big deal at all, but I'm just curious if the old HTML is saved off anywhere.

(Aside: I think I'm making up the phrase "baked HTML". What am I supposed to call that?)

Comment: 'parsed markdown (in HTML format)'...? (html part optional)

Comment: "Totally high HTML"?

Comment: Not sure if [this helps](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/revisions-by-ids#ids=5001&filter=!FcbKgRqyvKJuWvK3F40g7Xryu1&site=japanese&run=true)?

Comment: @rene Alas, no. This is also being processed through the current HTML renderer (the "body" key for revision 1 has `<strong>たる</strong>`, but in actuality the baked HTML prior to the rendering changes would have been `*たる*`).