# How do I bold some, but not all graphemes, of an italicized word?

Tags: support, markdown

How can I bold only m' in *Je **m’** évanouis*, without the space between m' and évanouis?

`*Je **m’**évanouis*` fails:

> *Je **m’**évanouis*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Markdown change: Intra-word emphasis now works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240354/markdown-change-intra-word-emphasis-now-works)

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog It's not a duplicate. I updated why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use formatting inside words *like t**h**is* - no space is needed.

**EDIT:**

Based on the clarifying edit, the `’` character seems to be messing up the markdown rendering (IMHO, this is a bug). You can work around it, though, by using inline HTML for the bolding (i..e, `<b>text</b>`):

```
*Je <b>m’</b>évanouis*
```

Which will render as: *Je **m’**évanouis*

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal I see the issue now  - see my edited answer

Answer (score 5):

If something does not work in Markdown, resort to HTML:

```
*Je <b>m’</b>évanouis*
```

produces

> *Je **m’**évanouis*