# Text formatting after a dot renders correctly at first but shows incorrectly once chat message has been posted

Tags: bug, chat, markdown

When putting text formatting after a dot in chat, it appears to render correctly at first:

> [image: Italics after a dot render as italics]

But when the chat message is posted, it renders incorrectly, with the formatting characters showing up:

> [image: Italics after a dot don't render as italics, formatting characters show up instead]

Not sure why the server-side Markdown renderer doesn't support it while the client-side renderer does. Either the server-side renderer should support it, or the client-side renderer shouldn't.

Just to make it clear...*it does work in posts*. But not in comments, see below; I'll probably file a separate bug for that.

Comment: It appears it...*doesn't work in comments either*.

Comment: According to [the original announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240354/323179) of intra-word emphasis, it's not supposed to work following punctuation.

Comment: @Laurel The fact that my example works in posts means it should probably work in comments and in chat messages.

Comment: Also, if it's not supposed to work, they should fix the client-side renderer so that it doesn't appear correctly when initially posting the message.