# Invalid markdown result for italics beginning with apostrophe at end of word

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-rendering

When Markdown code includes italicized text beginning with an apostrophe at the end (or in the middle) of a word, the result incorrectly displays the `*`s.

Ex:

#### code

```
Second*'s*
```

#### Result

> Second*'s*

The expected behavior is to display the `'s` italicized as depicted [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dfoverdx/j5vqck1x/).

[image: Correct rendering of markdown]

Comment: I think this is by design, since apostrophes probably count as punctuation. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240354/323179).