# Is there a way to put bold text after a punctuation sign in comments?

Tags: support, comments, markdown

According to [this announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240354/643262) (is this the last announcement on the matter?), Markdown emphasis (bold or italics) inside a word is possible, as long as it does not happen directly next to a punctiation sign:

> 2. If a single or double asterisk is supposed to be interpreted as intra-word emphasis, it cannot have punctuation on one side; it actually must be inside a word. An example of an edge case this solves is [...]

However, in posts (questions or answers), SE will happily render emphasized text after a dot:

- A /8 broadcast IPv4 address should end in 255. For example, 192.168.1.**255**

This does not work in comments, as can be seen in this picture:
[image: bold text after a dot is not possible in comments]

**Is there a way to emphasize text directly after a punctuation sign in a comment?**

(**Note**: my initial use case for this feature was [this comment](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/35042/por-qu%C3%A9-est%C3%A1-en-may%C3%BAscula-esta-a-en-el-ejemplo-del-dle-la-administraci%C3%B3n#comment62822_35043), where I copied a line of HTML code and wanted to highlight **la** in <span class="i1">**la**</span>. It would be great to have a solution for that too, but I understand that that might be too much to ask from comment formatting).

Comment: .**example that it does not work in comments**

Comment: the comment markdown is different / has a limited set of features it supports and that is unlikely to change. You can't achieve what you want with comment markdown.

Comment: Use some spaces

Comment: Intra-word emphasis doesn't work in comments, only in posts.

Comment: . **example that it does not work in comments**. Ideally, there should be a space after full stops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a workaround for this specific situation.

I just verified it worked by posting it as a comment below the question—but then removed the comment in order to turn it into this answer.

Use the [Bold Text Generator](https://boldtext.io/) website, and generate the text you want in bold, then copy and paste that into the comment.

In this case, 192.168.1.**255** will appear in the comment as:

> 192.168.1.

(You can copy and paste the above into a comment to test it.)

---

One thing to note about this is that not all devices display Unicode characters in the same way. It's possible that doing this would have the number in bold show up in an unexpected way for some people. But, in most cases, it should work.