# Comment markdown formatting doesn't render correctly when immediately followed by a forward slash

Tags: support, bug, comments, markdown

Consider either of the following Markdown formatting examples:

```
a**b**/c
a*b*/c
```

They will (as expected) render as a**b**/c and a*b*/c, respectively, in posts. However, in comments, it does not work for some reason.

This is especially useful for links. For example, I ran into that issue while writing [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/949344) on MSO:

> It's also strange that the link in the Products menu is still stackoverflow.co**m**/teams (which redirects to stackoverflow.co/teams).

which didn't work and was instead displayed as:

> It's also strange that the link in the Products menu is still stackoverflow.co**m**/teams (which redirects to stackoverflow.co/teams).

Can this be fixed?

And does anyone have a workaround for this for now? I tried inserting a [zero-width space character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) before the forward slash, but it didn't work.

Comment: This is a test to demonstrate: a**b**/c.

Comment: Related: *[Markdown change: Intra-word emphasis now works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240354/markdown-change-intra-word-emphasis-now-works)*

Comment: [A candidate workaround](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350028/is-there-a-way-to-put-bold-text-after-a-punctuation-sign-in-comments/350045#350045) using Unicode.

Comment: Comments markdown is lesser and different, this is most likely by design.